# How to correctly replace RAM on my machine

Tags: laptop, memory, hardware-rec

It's time for an update for my laptop. I tried to google some solutions to my problem but lots of different opinions/info out there.

I have the following model laptop: ASUS Q552U It currently has 12gb of RAM.
I need to upgrade to 16,24 or 32. Depending on what's supported. I cannot find any info on this laptop on the web.

I downloaded and ran speccy and got the following info:

[image: specs]

So, it uses ASUSTek COMPUTER INC. Q552UB motherboard. How do I know what is the max amount of ram is supported?

Detailed info on the motherboard:

[image: motherboard]

And detailed info on the ram:
[image]

After looking at the RAM details I have more questions than before:

It says that my laptop has 2 slots and one is taken with 12gb stick.
But below is says that slot #1 is taken by Hyundai electronics 8gb stick.

How can I find out if I can buy an additional 16gb and add it to my laptop? Should I replace an existing module as well? I cannot find Hyundai RAM anywhere.

Comment: [Crucial US | DRAM, Solid State Drive (SSD) & Memory Upgrades](http://www.crucial.com/) and use the system scanner

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for your comment. Crucial doesn't have my exact model but they have a similar model Q552UB When I go through their wizard it only presents me with 8gb ram modules. So, I have my existing 12gb in one slot and max I can add is 8gb? Does hyundai = crucial?

Comment: ? Your question says you have a Q552UB

Comment: @DavidPostill I have Q552U

Comment: But Motherboard is Q552UB, you are correct. Not sure if those are the same. So, it looks like max memory is 16gb which can be achieved by two 8gb DDR3 sticks. I think you are right